# SAS SQL Datepart function returning odd values

Tags: sql, formatting, sas

I'm having a massive problem with a project that I just can't seem to get right. I'm trying to modify my data variable as its currently in a datetime format. The first data is 30Mar12:00:00:00. I've been advised to use the code below but it returns a value like 30mar60:5:30:00. I just want the date component and have no idea how the data even got exported in this format as it wasn't like this in Microsoft Access. I've tried several mods to this code but again just comes up completely blank or sends an error message.

```
proc sql; update dataset set date = DATEPART(date); quit;
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please advise what data type and format the variable date is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the variable date is numeric and formatted as DATETIME.  Once you've carried out the conversion, just change the format to something like DATE9. A SAS datetime value is the number of seconds since 01 Jan 1960, whereas dates are the number of days since 01 Jan 1960.  Both are stored as numbers, so using the correct format to display the value is key.  Example below.

```
data _null_;
a='30Mar12:00:00:00'dt;
b=datepart(a);
c=b;
format a b datetime. c date9.;
put a b c;
run;
```

Comment: It is numeric and the format is DATETIME16. and its numeric. That makes sense as my dates have just all turned into 1960.

Comment: Solved my problem. You're a life saver Keith.

Comment: No problem.  When your data was imported from Access, it obviously defaulted the variable to datetime